# is there a way in Simulink to use the same set of blocks on multiple signals (without copying those blocks)?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am implementing some head tracking and I get 2 matrices of horizontal velocities. (A vector field decomposed into vertical and horizontal velocities). For each of these matrices I do some math to calculate the actual head tracking.

My question is, is there a way to do that math (which is a set of blocks) on both matrices without copying the math blocks onto each signal?

It's hard to explain so here's a screen shot of my model:
[image: simulink model]

You can see that the "complex to real-imag" block has 2 outputs (this is the little one in the middle). The mean block and the integrator circuit then calculate the head velocity and position for the real matrix (horizontal position). I want to do exactly the same routine on the imaginary matrix (vertical direction). Obviously I can just copy the blocks, but surely there must be a better way of doing it? In a way I'm looking for an analogue of a loop in "normal programming" like C or something, where a block of code is executed several times on different inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to easily reuse a set of blocks is to [create a subsystem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f4-53172.html) out of them. In your case, you can [create a subsystem by grouping existing blocks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f4-53172.html#f4-7371), then simply copy and paste your subsystem to use it for your imaginary output.

Although potentially more complicated, you could also look into using [mux signals](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/mux.html) to avoid having to copy parts of your model.

Comment: Is there a way to link these subsystems so that a change in one will propagate to all of its clones?

Comment: @codenoob: Not that I know of, which is why I listed another option in my answer (mux signals) that you may want to check out.

Comment: You could try creating a variable in the work space and making your values in the simulink model point to that variable i.e. add a gain block and where it asks for a value insert the name K, then set K = 0.5 in the work space

Answer (score 5):

You can create a Library in Simulink that contains code you can reference multiple times.

Go to File -> New -> Library.  In the model window that opens, you can create any number of subsystems with whatever code you want.  Then, just drag a subsystem from the library into your model.  The subsystem will now appear in your model with a little arrow icon in the lower left.  This indicates that the subsystem in the model is a link.  You can drag as many instances of the library subsystem into your model as you wish, just as you can call a function as many times as you wish in any other programming language.

If you right-click on the subsystem in your model, you can select "Link Options -> Go To Library Block" to get back to the library.  You can make changes in your model and propogate them back to the library as well.

Comment: This is a bit late question, but what if, I have used **global variables** within **Level-2 MATLAB S-Function Callback Methods**. No the global variables are used by both copies of the block, so the second block is overwritting the first block result. I want the variables to be global only within the block callbacks, and not in the complet **Simulink File** . Does Anyone have an idea?